# Change Vector Type keep Names

Tags: r

Sorry, if this is a duplicate. I could not find an answer.

I have a named vector (logical in this case):

```
a <- c("a" = TRUE, "b" = TRUE, "c" = FALSE, "e" = FALSE)

a
a     b     c     e 
TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

If I turn it into an integer, the names are gone.

```
> as.integer(a)
[1] 1 1 0 0
```

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
a <- +a
```

such that

```
> a
a b c e 
1 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can preserve the attributes of `a` by using `[]`

```
a[] <- as.integer(a)
#a b c e 
#1 1 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Some alternatives

```
class(a) <- "integer"
a b c e 
1 1 0 0
```

Or

```
ifelse(a, 1L, 0L)
a b c e 
1 1 0 0
```